# How to check any element has specific attribute or not

Tags: jquery

suppose image tag has custom attribute like "originalSrc" or something like this.
before accessing that attribute can i check that img tag has that attribute or not by jquery.

```
$("img.lazyload").each(function() {
$(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("original"));
$(this).removeAttr("original");
```

});

here i remove attribute like  `$(this).removeAttr("original");`
before remove it i want to check that img tag has the "original" attribute or not. if it has "original" attribute then i will remove it. so if there anything such checking is possible by jquery then please let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var attr = $(this).attr('original'); 
if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) { 
//assign to src
}
```

Comment: anyway thanks...if i write the code like this way does it work.... if ($(this).attr('original') !== 'undefined' && $(this).attr('original') !== false) 
{
  // my code goes here
}

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#id[attr]').length
```

This should do the trick

As for as your problem you can just do

```
 $('img[originalSrc]').length
```

Better still you can do

```
$('img[originalSrc]').bind('eventname',function(){

//do something
});
```

Comment: plzz come with a sample code. i just do not understand ur code.

Comment: 1) my first question :- we generally attach event handler with html element not with element attribute....so why r u attaching event handler with html element attribute....can u explain detail.

Comment: 2) my second question :- why r u checking length like $('img[originalSrc]').length. what it gives and if no attribute found called originalSrc then what will return....plzz discuss. thanks

Answer (score 1):

please try below code..

```
if ($(this).attr('original')) {
// attribute exists
} else {
// attribute does not exist
}
```

This would be helpful to you.

Thanks.

Comment: u got a negative mark...so does ur code works or not? i am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Hy,
if you want to check if an html Element or attribute is available in jquery simply use that

```
$('#id[attr]').length
```

otherwise you could try to get the value of the attribute and then check if its valid

```
var attribute = $(this).attr('original'); 
if (typeof attribute !== 'undefined' && attribute !== false) { 
//save to other value
}
```